# Как использовать флешку с ext3/ext4 для любого пользователя?

Tags: ubuntu

Проблема такова: работаю на нескольких компах и информацию нужно переносит с одного на другой с помощью флешки. Пользователи везде разные, а под рутом всё делать, сами понимаете, не комильфо. Постоянно менять права и владельцев файлов - слишком долго и накладно.

На флешке также есть исполняемые файлы, символические ссылки. FAT* не подходит. Если с исполняемыми файлами ещё можно в fstab поколдовать, то с владельцем такое на ext не работает.

Режим 777 тоже плохая идея. Как сделать так, чтобы на флешку можно было бы записать информацию с сохранением всех аттрибутов файлов любому пользователю?
Что-то вроде пользователя "Все" из Windows для NTFS.

Поиск в Интернете выдаёт только рекомендации по созданию загрузочной флешки с Ubuntu.

Comment: а почему бы не писать tar на FAT

Comment: @Pavel Gridin занимает время и место. Но как вариант можно рассматривать.

Comment: Так сделайте на флешке аналог каталога home. В корень пишут все, дальше каждый в свою. Обратите внимание, что права пользователя будут работать только там, где есть такой пользователь с тем же id. А сеть чем вам не мила?

Comment: @becouse вот именно, что id разные.

Comment: Тогда не ясна задача. Секретность? Тогда флешку невозможно использовать по определению. Просто передача файлов? Тогда используется сеть.

Comment: @becouse выделенный сервер с данными... Попытаюсь добиться выделения АО.

Comment: Вот тут развёрнутый ответ на ваш вопрос https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126213/can-i-port-user-permissions-across-computers-for-an-ext4-external-hard-drive

Comment: @becouse ссылку в ответ для закрытия вопрос. Я не очень в аглицком, но ситуация явно похожая. Буду смотреть в сторону bindfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная проблема в том, что linux хранит права для локальных пользователей.

Решения:

1. Использовать сеть
2. Использовать расширенные права доступа ACL
3. Использовать специальную ФС

Более подробно здесь https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126213/can-i-port-user-permissions-across-computers-for-an-ext4-external-hard-drive